# Google-closure : What's the difference between Goog.provide vs Goog.require

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

Can anyone tell me the difference. I've just started google-closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goog.provide creates a namespace; goog.require "imports" code from a given namespace so the closure compiler can find it.

Typically when you create a class, you'll *provide* a namespace for it, and *require* all of the namespaces that your classes uses directly.

More info (and examples) here: https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/tutorial

Comment: Minor correction, goog.require declares a dependency and the compiler checks that it is fulfilled.